# how to scale the interface for different screen sizes on MAUI

Tags: c#, maui

I'm looking for solutions to scale my interface.
The best solution would be to use something like Viewbox which is available in WPF. Alternatively, scaling font would save me.

Unfortunately I can't find any solution how to implement it.

Do exist and Control, property or maybe nuget, which allow scale interface?

Comment: Scale how? Explain your situation in detail. Maybe something like Styling, Selector, Trigger, State can help. You say scaling font can save. It may all come to one bool property, that will change your FontSize (zoom in, zoom out). I need context.

Comment: @H.A.H. I have interface in grid on the top i have label with text which on screen size 6.4" fit with font size 25. But when I open It on phone with 5.4" I don't see whole text and It is wrap. Also similar things on smaller screen text no fit in buttons.

Comment: I understand you now. But my methods cannot help you. Search something like that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74861267/maui-font-size-auto-resize-according-to-screen-or-window-width